# Finding Particular Solution of a Second Order Differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

The homogenous equation: $\ 28{e^{-2x}} { - 18e^{-3x}}$

I found the homogenous solution to the equation, however I am not sure how to find the particular solution when the differential equation is equal to 8. I tried using matlab but I'm not too sure if it's correct.

Comment: I am quite sure using Matlab is NOT what you are supposed to do.

Comment: $v_s$ is a constant right?

Comment: @Holo Yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $v_s$ is a constant we have $f(v'',v',v)=P(t)$ where $P$ is polynomial with degree $n$ (and $f$ is linear) . In this particular case $P$ is degree $0$. A second order ODE in this form has praticular solution in the form of $Q(x)$, where $Q$ is polynomial in the same degree as $P$, so in this case degree $0$.

Hence $Q(x)=a$:

$(a)''+5(a)'+6a=8\implies 6a=8\implies a=4/3$ so $v_p=4/3$

Comment: Oh what if it isn't a constant? for instance, the differential equation is equaled to 3(e^(−4t))

Comment: @JakeGinobi in this case our praticular solution will be in other form. If $P(t)=Ae^{Bt}$ the praticular solution will be in the same form(this is not always the case, but polynomials and exponentials are nice), well, $B$ is the same in $P$ and $v_p$ so the only variable is the constant coefficient

Comment: Thanks so much. I have one more question. I'm asked to find the complete solution, so would I just add the homogenous equation with the two particular solutions, or would I just add the homogenous equation with one particular solution and that equates to one complete solution, and do it for the other particular solution as well so it'll be a separate complete solution?

Comment: @JakeGinobi what do you mean $2$ praticular solutions? In if you have $P=8$ than $v_p=4/3$ is the only solution and if you have $P=3e^{-4t}$ then $v_p=Ce^{-4t}$ is the only solution (there is only one $C$, if you check you'll get $C=3/2$ if I did it right), only one of them is the praticular solution, and then you just add $v_h$ and $v_p$ to get to a solution

Answer (score 1):

If $v_s$ is constant, make the substitution $v = u + v_s/6.$ Then $u$ satisfies the homogeneous equation and you are done. If $v_s$ is not necessarily constant, use variation of parameters: look for solution in the form $v = v_0 f,$ where $v_0$ is the homogeneous solution.